# Use of unresolved identifier when creating a string

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am very new to swift, but i can work with javascript and php so thought this would make sense to me. I have read so many posts on this topic but non really explain mine. I have the following code which is pretty straight forward. I have several text fields with login information to pass on to php. But when i try to use the var from a function it is not possible. So i figured that out but when i try to redefine the vars outside of the function with different var i am still keep getting the error. This is the code so far

```
import UIKit

class RegisterPage: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordConfirmTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }





    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func registerTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text
        let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text
        let userConfirmPassword = userPasswordConfirmTextField.text


        // check for empty fields
        if(userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userConfirmPassword.isEmpty)
        {

            // Display alert message
            displayMyAlertMessage("Alle velden gelieve invullen");
            return;
        }

        //Check if passwords match
        if(userPassword != userConfirmPassword){

        // Display alert message
            displayMyAlertMessage("Wachtwoorden komen niet overeen");
            return;

        }

    }// end of registerTapped button





    // send data to server side


    static var urlConn: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://xxxxxxxxx")!
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:urlConn);



    var credLogin = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)"
```

the following line is giving the unresolved identifier error

```
var credLogin = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)"
```

i have tried so many different things, but i can't move the var in the function outside of it, and i have had also in other code blocks errors like this, i really would like to know how this works in swift.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you skipped out on all the important code, your error is because there's no `userEmail` or `userPassword` variables when you're creating the `credLogin` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `userEmail` and `userPassword` are declared within the scope of the `registerTapped` method. They are not visible outside this method.

Either put the line

```
var credLogin = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)"
```

in the method or declare the variables as instance variables right after `IBOutlet` declarations.

The code to *send data to server side* must be also executed within a method.

Comment: i have one more question how to declare it as instance variable? i tried so many things but nothing is working. the way i solved is the put everything in a function

func urlConnect(){
code
}

that worked and i have access to the var from iboutlet, but it is the only way i can get the code to work, which i think it not the correct way i think. However this all could be written as function as it will excute every time that piece of code after it checked if everything is filled in.

Comment: instance variables are declared on the same level as the `IBOutlet` declarations. In a view controller you can declare a variable as non-optional with a default value ``var userPassword = ""` or as optional `var userPassword : String?`. In your case I'd recommend to use the non-optional version.

Comment: i have done that several times and it is not working if i do not put them in func name(){}, onlywhen i put them in a method it is working. BUt i think i have it working now. thanks